# How to extract the link type and put it into an evar or a prop?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am using Adobe launch configured with Adobe Analytics extensions by opting library management set to "Manage the library for me". I need to extract exit link and store it in eVar or Prop. Is there any default code updated in Adobe to fetch the exit link or do i need to add java-script code manually. Need suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I did this in the Custom Code of Adobe Analytics tool in Adobe DTM some time back. This should be similarly set up in Adobe Launch. YMMV:

```
s.doPlugins = function(s) {
  if (s.linkType === 'e') { // this checks if this call is an exit link call.
    s.eVarN = s.linkURL;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this before and this will capture eVar value onload of next page/pagereload once after user clicks on exit link. Is there any way where we can use eVarN in the same pev1 exit call.

Comment: @eswaris If the exit link is launched in a new tab or browser window, it is possible that the eVarN is recorded in the next call on the page in the current window/tab (this can be reset by using `s.clearVars()` in post call callback). But to be recorded in the next page's call, that's something new to me. Unless there is a caching mechanism carrying the values over to the next page or the site being a single page app, it shouldn't have happened.

Comment: Thanks, This gives me an idea. I updated the above code and captured linkURL in a eVar. But I am not getting value in eVar and if i update a console.log(s.linkURL) to capture linkURL and this works. Any idea y my eVar s not capturing exit linkURL

Comment: @eswaris did you set `s.linkTrackVars` as well?